# AddConfigurationStore using Oracle.EntityFrameworCore(2.18.0-beta3) OracleException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: identityserver4

I am using `EntityFramework Core` for configuration and operational data using `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore(2.18.0-beta3)` but receive `"OracleException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"`.

`Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore(2.18.0-beta3)` is working as I can use "MVC Controller with Views, using Entity Framework" to scaffold a new Controller which will create and edit Oracle tables (Clients and IdentityResources Controllers were created).

Startup.cs ConfigureServices contains the following configuration:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
              // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
              .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
              {
                  options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                      b.UseOracle(connectionString);

              })
              .AddOperationalStore(options =>
              {
                  options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                      b.UseOracle(connectionString);
                  options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
              });
```

The Welcome to IdentityServer4 (version 2.4.0.0) page shows, and will route to the controller options, but the "discover document", (http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration), returns
`"OracleException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"`.

Answer (score 2):

Got this to work with Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore (2.19.0-beta4).  A couple of things that I learned along the way:

1) Many instances of Oracle adhere to the SQL-92 standard which limits objects (including table names and column names) to 30 characters; several of the default  `IdentityServer4` "Client" table column names exceed 30 characters. The EF migration was modified to adapt the column name character limit.

```
b.Property<bool>("AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken")
        .HasColumnName("AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdTok");
```

2) Oracle handles incrementing primary keys differently than SQLServer. The EF migration `Oracle:ValueGenerationStrategy` property is used for all primary keys.

```
b.Property<int>("Id")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .HasAnnotation("Oracle:ValueGenerationStrategy", OracleValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
```

3)  Oracle table names are not case sensitive if they are created all uppercase; if they are created mixed case, they are case sensitive.  I was able to get `IdentityServer4` working with Oracle using default `IdentityServer4` table names.  However, I chose to change the table names to all uppercase by changing the EF properties to upper case:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(name: "IS4_CLIENT",

b.ToTable("IS4_CLIENT"), 

principalTable: "IS4_CLIENT",
```

The `IdentityServer4` configuration store properties needed to be changed to match the altered upper case table names. The following is the extension class that was used to configure `IdentityServer4` `AddConfigurationStore` and the `AddOperationalStore`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities;

namespace is4ef.Extensions
{
    public static class Is4BuilderExtensions
    {
        public static string IdentityResource { get; private set; }

        public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddIs4ConfigurationStore(
            this IIdentityServerBuilder builder, string connectionString)
        {

            string assemblyNamespace = typeof(Is4BuilderExtensions)
                .GetTypeInfo()
                .Assembly
                .GetName()
                .Name;

            builder
                .AddConfigurationStore(options => {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                        b.UseOracle(connectionString, optionsBuilder =>
                            optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(assemblyNamespace)
                                .UseOracleSQLCompatibility("12"));
                    options.DefaultSchema = "X13663";
                    options.ApiClaim.Name = "IS4_AIPCLAIM";
                    options.ApiResourceProperty.Name = "IS4_APIPROPERTY";
                    options.ApiResource.Name = "IS4_APIRESOURCE";
                    options.ApiScopeClaim.Name = "IS4_APISCOPECLAIM";
                    options.ApiScope.Name = "IS4_APISCOPE";
                    options.ApiSecret.Name = "IS4_APISECRET";
                    options.ClientClaim.Name = "IS4_CLIENTCLAIM";
                    options.ClientCorsOrigin.Name = "IS4_CLIENTCORSORIGIN";
                    options.ClientGrantType.Name = "IS4_CLIENTGRANTTYPE";
                    options.ClientIdPRestriction.Name = "IS4_CLIENTIDPRESTRICTION";
                    options.ClientPostLogoutRedirectUri.Name = "IS4_CLIENTPOSTLOGOUTREDIRECTURI";
                    options.ClientProperty.Name = "IS4_CLIENTPROPERTY";
                    options.ClientRedirectUri.Name = "IS4_CLIENTREDIRECTURI";
                    options.Client.Name = "IS4_CLIENT";
                    options.ClientScopes.Name = "IS4_CLIENTSCOPE";
                    options.ClientSecret.Name = "IS4_CLIENTSECRET";
                    options.IdentityClaim.Name = "IS4_IDENTITYCLAIM";
                    options.IdentityResourceProperty.Name = "IS4_IDENTITYPROPERTY";
                    options.IdentityResource.Name = "IS4_IDENTITYRESOURCE";
                })
                .AddOperationalStore(options => {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                        b.UseOracle(connectionString, optionsBuilder =>
                            optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(assemblyNamespace)
                                .UseOracleSQLCompatibility("12"));
                    options.DefaultSchema = "X13663";
                    options.DeviceFlowCodes.Name = "IS4_DEVICECODE";
                    options.PersistedGrants.Name = "IS4_PERSISTEDGRANT";
            });
            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```